# Получение uri всех видео файлов из галереи

Tags: java, android, gallery

Надо мне вывести в `RecycleView` видео из галереи в миниатюре, с которыми можно взаимодействовать. Вопрос, как получить список  со всеми видео, а точнее с их `uri`, что использовать?

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String[] id = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.activity_main, id);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: локальных видео?

Comment: Да, локальных
С телефона на котором запущена программа

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman извините, моё первоначальное сообщение было отредактировано, а дополнительный текст был удален.

Comment: В вопросе может быть только одна проблема. Если у вас несколько проблем, создайте другие вопросы по каждой из них.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `MediaStore` и [MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.html), получить миниатюры можно через [MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.html). Аналогичный вопрос есть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997775/how-to-get-list-of-videos-on-sd-card).

Примерный код:

```
public static void printNamesToLogCat(Context context) {
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA };
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("Video path: ", c.getString(0));
        }
        c.close();
    }
}
```